# Whats the best algorithm for Non Disjoint Set Union?

Tags: algorithm, union, complexity-theory, set

Lets say there are two (non disjoint) sets of points (cartesian space), what is the best case complexity algorithm to perform the union of the two sets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the point coordinates are arbitrary and there is no special relation between them, I don't see this problem as a geometric specific problem. It is the generic problem of efficiently merging S1 and S2 into a new set S.

I know about two options:

1) When the sets are stored in a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tables) (actually a hash set), the union takes O(|S1|+|S2|) in **average**.

2) If you store the structures in a [balanced search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), you can achieve a worst case time of O(|S1| * Log(|S1|)), assuming that |S1|>|S2|.

Comment: Thanks, I think hashtable seems like the most practical one, will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if the sets are in a balanced search tree, I think you can do it in O(|S2| (1+log (|S1|/|S2|)), where |S1|>=|S2|. This is optimal in the worst case.