# approximated algorithm of union two non-disjoint sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

[Whats the best algorithm for Non Disjoint Set Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708070/whats-the-best-algorithm-for-non-disjoint-set-union) is about the precise algorithm of non-disjoint set union.

With balanced trees, its union cost is n*log(n) where n is the average size of a set; and its membership cost is log(n); the space cost is n if we use balanced trees. With hashmaps, its union cost is O(n), find cost is log(n), and space cost is n.

My question is if we allow more space, can time cost be smaller?

A native approach is like this

If two sets are s1=(a, b) and s2=(b, c), we create a new node s12 whose two children are s1 and s2. Given this, s1 is also a tree with leaves a and b; s2 is similar. So all the sets are like this.

```
       s21
       /  \
      s1  s2
     / \  / \
     a b  b c
```

This is basically a union-find on a non-disjoint set.

To check is v in a set, we traverse the whole tree of the set. So union's cost is O(1), and find's cost is log(n) on average. But the space cost can be a lot because this way we will be creating a lot of trees for the same set. For example,

```
          s
         / \
        s  a
        /\ 
        a a
```

Another native approach would be using a long bit vector to mark which element is used in a set assuming set elements are limited. For example, if my sets can contain only 10k elements, the bit vector's length is 10k, and its i-th bit is 1 iff this element is in the set. With this, set union is turned into a bit vector or. However, this space cost is high for a sparse set, and run time union cost is also same to the number of total possible elements.

Is there a better (using less space but still getting smaller time cost) approach than these?

Comment: can't you just use a hashmap ? space O(n), find O(1)

Comment: hashmap's union is still O(n). I was wondering if an approximated algorithm may have complexity similar to union-find on disjoint sets. I updated the question about the hashmap complexity.

Comment: If I understand that correctly you just put two sets into one data structure, but that datastructure is not balanced tree anymore, therefore lacking all the advantages of balanced tree. You have two balanced subtrees now and you have to traverse them both all the time...

Comment: Right. this native approach does not preserve balanced invariance or even ensure nodes are unique in the tree. So it does not quite work.  I used it simply as an example to show how using more space could make runtime smaller, unfortunately this native approach uses too much space... so I was wondering if there is a better idea.